# Getting elements from a unicode text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string like:

```
u'{"nick":"NICK","name":"NAME","email":"name@example.com","phone_gsm":"","phone":"","birthday":"","location":"UK","address":"","job":"","gender":"male","permission_of_contact":"NO"}'
```

I need to get proper data so I need to get for example nick of a user, email of a user etc. Is there a way to get them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module

```
import json
my string = u'{"nick":"NICK","name":"NAME","email":"name@example.com","phone_gsm":"","phone":"","birthday":"","location":"UK","address":"","job":"","gender":"male","permission_of_contact":"NO"}'

data = json.loads(my_string)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also gave an error: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: see my udapte using json.loads

Comment: json.loads instead of json.load solved my problem thank you.